# How to trigger click event when using "a" tag

Tags: javascript, css, html, performance

I am using jquery flip plugin. https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ to toggle between two div elements. I have one button which I use to toggle between two div elements. I am able to achieve it. But I want to have the same functionality when I click on "a" tag.

Working Perfectly:

```
    <button type="button" id = "toggle1" class = "toggle">Click Me!</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip({
 trigger: 'manual'
  });
$('#toggle1').click(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip('toggle');
  });

});
 </script>
```

Now I want to replace the button with

```
<a id = "toggle1"><i class="some-icon"></a>
```

When I click on the a tag nothing happens. Can someone guide me.

**EDIT**

```
    <div class = "flip" id = "flip1">
        <div class = "front">
                               <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
                             // some front stuff here
                               </div>
                             </div>
                               <div class = "back">

                                <div id = "tableAnchor1" class="x_content">
                              // some flipped stuff here
                              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Its not working when added in the Menu bar of div. I am adding my code here.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="x_panel">
      <div class="x_title">
         <h2>INCOME<small>Sessions</small></h2>
         <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
            <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class          ="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="settings.html">Settings 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><button type="button" id = "toggle1" class = "toggle">Click Me!</button>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a id="toggle1">link</a><!-- <a id = "toggle1"><i class="fa fa-external-link user-profile-icon">nm</i></a> -->
            </li>
            <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class = "flip" id = "flip1">
         <div class = "front">
            <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class = "back">
            <div id = "tableAnchor1" class="x_content">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: <a id = "toggle1"><i class="some-icon"></a>

Comment: Please provide a runnable example.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: I dont know how to provide runnable example. Kindly guide me. I have added more code in the question. Kindly see. Am I using <a> click event correctly?

Comment: Edit your answer, you'll find a small icon with "< >". Click on it, and paste your code there. We can help you then

Comment: Everything works perfectly on button click!

Comment: Add `href="#"` to `a`. Use the same function (`.click(...`) but `return false;` from it.

Comment: Then I don't understand why it would be any different with an a tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach a click event on 2 different elements with the same `id`, you need another `id` for the anchor `a`, like `toggle2`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip({
 trigger: 'manual'
  });
$('#toggle1').click(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip('toggle');
  });
$('#toggle2').click(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip('toggle');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
  
  
<a id = "toggle2"><i class="some-icon">Click me too</i></a>

<button type="button" id = "toggle1" class = "toggle">Click Me!</button>

<div class = "flip" id = "flip1">
  <div class = "front">
    <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
      // some front stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "back">

    <div id = "tableAnchor1" class="x_content">
      // some flipped stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess issue is something else. I have edited the question. Can you see once.

Comment: @Unbreakable Not it is not, you still use same id on both button and anchor, which you can't

Comment: Yes got it! Thank you so so much!

Comment: Really appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work with the anchor tag to me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#flip1").flip({
 trigger: 'manual'
});
$('#toggle1').click(function() {
  $("#flip1").flip('toggle');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>
  


<a id="toggle1"><i class="some-icon">link</a>

    <div class = "flip" id = "flip1">
        <div class = "front">
                               <div id = "chartAnchor1" class="x_content">
                                 test1
                               </div>
                             </div>
                               <div class = "back">

                                <div id = "tableAnchor1" class="x_content">
                                  test2
                              </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not working when I am putting the anchor tag at a particular place. Can you see the edited version of question

Comment: You have the `button` and `a` with the `id="toggle1"`. You'll need to use unique ids for each. Because `button` is rendered first with the `id`, the link id does not get the event handler attached.